# no function clause matching in Plug.Conn.send_file/5

Tags: controller, elixir, phoenix-framework

I am trying to create a new route that will allow users to download the files they have uploaded. I created this route under the "/" scope.

```
get "/media/:filepath", MediaFilesController, :download
```

For now, I'm just trying to send images that are located in a folder `uploads` that is located at the root of the project. In short, if someone tries to access `/media/file.png`, it will send the file located at `<project_folder>/uploads/file.png`. Here's the code for it:

```
defmodule App.MediaFilesController do
  use App.Web, :controller
  import Plug.Conn

  @media_folder "/uploads"

  def download(conn, %{"filepath" => filepath}) do
    path = "#{System.cwd}/#{@media_folder}/#{filepath}"
    {:ok, file} = File.open(path)
    conn
    |> put_resp_content_type("image/png")
    |> send_file(200, file)
  end
end
```

When I try to load the URL `/media/file.png`, I'm getting this error:

```
[error] #PID<0.579.0> running App.Endpoint terminated Server: localhost:4000 (http) Request: GET /media/file.png
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (FunctionClauseError) no function clause matching in Plug.Conn.send_file/5
```

I do not understand why I'm getting this error. The [documentation](http://www.phoenixframework.org/docs/file-uploads) precisely says:

> send it back to the client with `Plug.Conn.send_file/5`.

Why am I getting this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`send_file/5` expects a path, not a file.

So in the end, the function looks like this:

```
def download(conn, %{"filepath" => filepath}) do     
  path = "#{System.cwd}/#{@media_folder}/#{filepath}"
  conn                                               
  |> put_resp_content_type("image/png")              
  |> send_file(200, path)                            
end
```

Comment: To add to this answer, the typing for this function on the [docs page](https://hexdocs.pm/plug/Plug.Conn.html#send_file/5)
says: "filename :: binary".